# Como identificar o evento de fechar no MagnificPopup

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

Preciso identificar onde o usuário clicou para fechar o lightbox MagnificPopup, pois vou executar uma ação sobre isso.

Opção:

1. -Fechar x
2. -Escape
3. -background que é a parte escura

.

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
                    items: {
                        src: '#thanksModal',
                    },
                    type: 'inline'
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar essa propriedade:

```
close: function() {
  console.log('Acabo de fechar.');
}
```

No seu caso, ficaria:

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
  items: {
    src: '#thanksModal',
  },
  type: 'inline',
  close: function() {
    console.log('Acabo de fechar!');
  }
});
```

Para saber mais, queira checar a [documentação](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#events) deste plugin.